# VB.Net - Registrykey

Tags: c#, vb.net, registry, regedit

I like to enumerate the Registrykeys.
I am so far:

```
  Dim key As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\")
    For Each subkey In key.GetSubKeyNames
        ListBox1.Items.Add(subkey.ToString)
    Next
```

But I like to specify the Registry hive in a Function parameter like this:

```
    Private Function listregistry(ByVal hive As RegistryHive, ByVal path As String)
    Dim key As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = My.Computer.Registry.hive.OpenSubKey(path)
    For Each subkey In key.GetSubKeyNames
        ListBox1.Items.Add(subkey.ToString)
    Next
End Function
```

That gives me this error:

> 'hive' is not a member of 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.MyServices.RegistryProxy'

What can I do to fix this?

Well I was able to get it to work, but this is a bit sloppy, how can I optimize this:

```
 Private Sub ListRegistryKeys(ByVal RegistryHive As String, ByVal RegistryPath As String)
    Select Case RegistryHive
        Case "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"
            Dim key As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(RegistryPath)
            For Each subkey In key.GetSubKeyNames
                ListBox1.Items.Add(subkey.ToString)
            Next
        Case "HKEY_CURRENT_USER"
            Dim key As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(RegistryPath)
            For Each subkey In key.GetSubKeyNames
                ListBox1.Items.Add(subkey.ToString)
            Next
        Case "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT"
            Dim key As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = My.Computer.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(RegistryPath)
            For Each subkey In key.GetSubKeyNames
                ListBox1.Items.Add(subkey.ToString)
            Next
        Case "HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG"
            Dim key As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = My.Computer.Registry.CurrentConfig.OpenSubKey(RegistryPath)
            For Each subkey In key.GetSubKeyNames
                ListBox1.Items.Add(subkey.ToString)
            Next
        Case "HKEY_USERS"
            Dim key As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = My.Computer.Registry.Users.OpenSubKey(RegistryPath)
            For Each subkey In key.GetSubKeyNames
                ListBox1.Items.Add(subkey.ToString)
            Next
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, I tried your code...

Comment: Private Sub listregistry(ByVal hive As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey, ByVal path As String)
        Dim key As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = hive.OpenSubKey(path)
        For Each subkey In key.GetSubKeyNames
            Debug.WriteLine(subkey.ToString)
        Next
    End Sub

Comment: That does not work :/

Comment: hmm... passing strings and doing a select case statement on arbitrary values is not enumeration.. declare an enumeration by using the Enum statement. Look into Flag Enum as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Function listregistry(ByVal hive As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive, ByVal path As String)
    Dim key As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(hive, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryView.Default).OpenSubKey(path)

    For Each subkey In key.GetSubKeyNames
        ListBox1.Items.Add(subkey.ToString)
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: And what might those errors be?  Just showing the blue underlined errors does not help.

Comment: 1) 'OpenBaseKey' is not a member of 'Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey'       
2) 'RegistryView' is not a member of 'Win32'.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: 3.5 for this project.

Comment: I see that it works for .net 4.0 and later, but is there a workarround for older .net versions? Because in 3.5 and the older ones, RegistryView is unknown.

Comment: The workaround is the code that you posted, which, as you stated, is a bit sloppy.  I would suggest refactoring, though, to move the `For Each` loop outside the `Select Case` so you only have it once.

Comment: I tried it like this by using arrays, but I am not sure how to add the subkeys after the comapred key is correct: